# Rails namespace helpers not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In app/controllers/admin I created dashboad_controller.rb:

```
class Admin::DashboardController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end
end
```

From 'rake routes | grep activity' I get:

```
            admin_activity_logs GET    /admin/activity_logs(.:format)               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/activity_logs"}
```

and other routes. My route.rb looks like this:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :activity_logs
  end
```

When I try to create a link using the helper:

```
= link_to 'Activity Log', admin_activity_logs
```

I get

```
undefined local variable or method `admin_activity_logs' for #<#<Class:0x106077ec8>:0x1060760c8>
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `_path`.

```
= link_to 'Activity Log', admin_activity_logs_path
```

Comment: or the `_url` a bit different